# how to put a 2d string array in if statement?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, if-statement

i have problem comparing a string 2d array with 'X' in if statement

I'm trying to compare every cell in my array with 'X' but i get "no match for 'operator == ' error in line 14, so i guess i have problem putting the array inside this if statement

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        string M[n][n];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
               cin>>M[i][j];
               if(M[i][j]=='X')
                   k++;
           }
       }

         cout<<k<<endl;

         return 0;
   }
```

the error in line 14 "the if line" and it says "no match for 'operator == ' error

Comment: `'X'` is not a string.

Comment: `"X"` might be though.

Comment: To be more explicit, `M[i][j]` is a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and you are trying to compare it to `'X'`, which is a `char`. There is no such comparison implemented (a string of characters vs a single character). However, if you had instead written `"X"`, then that would be a `char *`, and that can be automatically converted into a `std::string` and therefore compared to `M[i][j]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might not be obvious if you would be coming from another language like Python, but in C++ there is a significant difference between using `""` and `''` for literal types. We only use `''` (single quotes) for `char` type. For std::string type (and other strings) we use `""` for comparision - which is also your case.

Therefore in your line:

```
if(M[i][j]=='X')
```

you need to use double quotes `""` to compare an element from M with a string:

```
if(M[i][j] == "X")
```

Alternatively, if you only store single characters in each cell of M, this could be a 2D array of `char`s.

Comment: did you just assume the OP is coming from Python or others?

Comment: I did not assume that, but if someone does come from Python or similar, I believe that this might not be obvious at the beginning, am I wrong?

Comment: I was more curious to understand how you came to that conclusion, not being funny, it could be that the OP is a beginner in C++ and has learning gaps.

Comment: Sure @SamerTufail, I guess that most likely OP is just a beginner in programming at all, but I just wanted to mention that sometimes even a "non-beginner" programmer may do that mistake.

Comment: I guess so, fair enough :).

Comment: @RoaaKoraiem if you have a new question ask a new question, the comments aren't the right place to ask new questions

Answer (score -1):

first declare a string variable and assign "X"
eg. `string s="X";`
after this compare s with each index
eg. `if(M[i][j]==s)`

code:

```
int main(){
int n;
    //here
    string s="X";
    cin >> n;
    string M[n][n];
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         cin>>M[i][j];
         //here
         if(M[i][j]==s) 
           k++;
       }
   }
}
```